# Finding Good BF3 Servers

Tags: battlefield-3

Can you give tips/guidelines/advice on how to find good games in BF3?

Before DICE allowed anyone and everyone to rent servers (Consoles), you could easily find a decent game by choosing Quick Match. The few DICE servers ensured decent size teams. Now I mostly get dropped into +200% ticket servers with very few players and often the teams are unbalanced ( 5 vs 10 ).

I usually play between 9pm to 1am CST throughout the week.

Comment: I totally agree with you here. Finding a good server on console is tough now. The teams just get stacked every game and they are always set to 200% tickets.

Comment: @dr01: Did I answer your question? If so, please mark as accepted. If not, please add more clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for servers that are still run by [DICE]. There are still some of them out there. Many private servers also put [DICE] in their name, and have them set up as DICE-like (standard tickets mainly). Others may say "tired of 500% tickets" or something. It usually takes a few minutes of searching, but once you find some, add them to your favorites. When you have several in your favorites that work for you, you should always be able to get into a decent game.

In short, use your Server Browser to its potential. Unfortunately, there is currently no way to sort by ticket count, so you have to put in a little extra work.